# How do I find the size of a column in GB?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, aggregate

I have two tables with attachments stored in my databse. People from multiple buildings use my application to upload attachments to the database (the files themselves are stored in type **bytea**). I need to figure out the total size (in GB) of the attachments for each building.

```
SELECT sum(octet_length(attachmentfile)) 
FROM schema.tattachments a, schema.trequests r, schema.tlocations l
WHERE r.location = l.locationid
AND a.reqid = r.reqid
AND r.sys_actntm > '2014-09-18'
GROUP BY l.building
```

The above SQL returns a bigint result separated by building:

```
    sum bigint
--|-----------
1 | 15782159611407981
2 | 1140653769
3 | 710849157667
```

etc...

How can I format this SQL statement so it will give me the info in GB or MB, rather than these large numbers?

Comment: case when > 100000... then divide when > 10000 then divide etc (Create a function for this.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PostgreSQL has some [system administration functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html) that will take care of this for you.  Something along these lines should work.

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(sum(octet_length(attachmentfile)::bigint)) 
FROM schema.tattachments a, schema.trequests r, schema.tlocations l
WHERE r.location = l.locationid
AND a.reqid = r.reqid
AND r.sys_actntm > '2014-09-18'
GROUP BY l.building;
```

You might be better off replacing octet_length() with pg_column_size(). Not sure how that would affect your query.